# How to convert YYMMDDhhmm formatted NVARCHAR into YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm:ss formatted DATETIME?

Tags: sql, sql-server, casting, type-conversion

For example:

The value `2208111603`(nvarchar) needs to be converted to `2022-08-11 00:00:00`(datetime).

The things I have tried and the corresponding errors I've got so far as follow:

`CAST(DATE_TIME AS numeric)` works but `CAST(CAST(DATE_TIME AS numeric) AS datetime)` returns Arithmetic Overflow Error.

`convert(datetime2, CAST(DATE_TIME AS numeric), 105)` returns

> Explicit conversion from data type numeric to datetime2 is not allowed

`CONVERT(datetime2, DATE_TIME , 105)` returns

> Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character
> string.

`CONVERT(datetime2, CONVERT(CHAR(10), DATE_TIME), 105)` returns

> Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character
> string.

Finally, I tried `PARSE(DATE_TIME AS date USING 'en-US')` which resulted in

> Error converting string value '2208111603' into data type date using
> culture 'en-US'.

The SQL Server's `CONVERT` function also has some built-in formats as a third parameter for converting varchar to datetime. So, I tried `SELECT convert(datetime,'2208111603',112)` which resulted in the same error (Msg 241):

> Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character
> string.

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: how get `2022-08-11 00:00:00` from `2208111603` ??? why `220811` isn't `1922-08-11` ?? and the end of part `1603` what is this ?

Comment: I was just typing to respond to you when @John came in and solved the problem. But thanks for your consideration.

Comment: "2208111603(nvarchar) needs to be converted to 2022-08-11 00:00:00(datetime)" - note that `datetime`  is a binary structure without a format. You want to convert '2208111603' to a `datetime` (the application determines how the value is displayed).

Comment: @JohnCappelletti Sorry it was a mistake

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With just a bit of string manipulation...

Note: this will assume century of 20

**Example**

```
Declare @S varchar(50) ='2208111603'

Select try_convert(datetime,stuff(stuff(@S,7,0,' '),10,0,':'))
```

**Results**

```
2022-08-11 16:03:00.000
```

A little bit ugly, but to overcome the century indicator you an nest a little logic to conditionally add 19.

```
Declare @S varchar(50) ='6408111603'

Select try_convert(datetime,case when left(@S,2)>'50' then '19' else '' end + stuff(stuff(@S,7,0,' '),10,0,':'))
```